# How do I validate paypal form with php data before submitting it to paypal

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have the following form

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="N8Q3XBTNBV8TY">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Team Name">Team Name</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I want to validate (using php) that the team name is at least three characters long before the form is submitted.  How would I implement this?

Comment: You either need to validate in JS and submit the form to PayPal from JS, or you need to submit this form to PHP that will validate the data and then submit to PayPal.

Answer (score 4):

You can't (if you're submitting directly to PayPal, as you are in your code example), using PHP.  But you can use javascript.

```
<script>
// using jQuery, just cuz it's easier for this sort of stuff
$('form[action*="paypal"]').submit(function(event) {
    if ($('input[name="on0"]').val().length < 3) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // alert, or use some other means of displaying an error to the user
        alert('Your Team Name must be at least 3 characters long');
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```